# Angular6 no pipeable combineLatest

Tags: angular6, rxjs6, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I have to upgrade Angular5 code to Angular6, but I have an issue with the static combineLatest.

```
export function test<T>(id: string | Observable<string>): OperatorFunction<T[], T> {

const id$ = asObservableIfNot(id);
return pipe(
  combineLatest(id$, (collection: T[], resolvedId) => {
    return collection.find(element => {
      return element.id === resolvedId;
    });
  }),
  distinctUntilChanged()
 );
}
```

In this case the combineLatest is import from rxjs/operators and return an OperatorFunction, but the static one return an Observable.

How can I convert this code in angular6 ?

Answer (score 0):

Since RxJs 6 you have to use pipe with map function.

```
someObservable.pipe(map(...))
```

Comment: Yes but I have not 'someObservable' available, It is a reusable pipe available in the application.
If I use map inside the pipe I lost my Observable and I can't use combineLatest